# How do I bind the backround row color of a listbox/listview in WP 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, background, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

So I made a converter and set up my list box like so:

```
<ListBox x:Name="QList" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Border Background="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource QColorConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate >
</ListBox>
```

However, when I run it, I get just the block right around the text that changes color, not the whole row.  How can I make the whole row background change color?

Answer (score 0):

Set ItemContainerStyle HorizontalAlignment to stretch.

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way I can do this for the vertical dimension.  What I am looking to do is bind the default color of the border.